# Which comments are included in the most common psql describe commands?

Tags: postgresql, comments, psql

I like making the lives of my future self and collaborators easier by using `COMMENT ON` to add comments on database objects. People can then see them when they're exploring the schema with `\d+` and `\df+` and so on.

However, some objects can accept comments, but `psql` won't display them where I would expect developers to typically go to learn about an object. For example, I can do `COMMENT ON POLICY ...` to add comments to an RLS policy, but they don't show up on `\d+` or `\dp+` for the table, which are the commands I'd normally use to inspect RLS policies.

What comments can I use and reasonably expect `psql` to show in an easily-accessible place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `COMMENT ON COLUMN` is visible in `\d+` for the relation.
- `COMMENT ON FUNCTION` is visible in `\df+` for the function. Since functions are stored as text, you can also include code comments in functions, and they will be visible to someone reading the function too.
- `COMMENT ON SCHEMA` is visible in `\dn+`
- `COMMENT ON ROLE` is visible in `\dg+`
- `COMMENT ON TYPE` is visible in `\dT` (unlike the other examples, you don't need the `+`)
- `COMMENT ON TABLE` or `VIEW` or `MATERIALIZED VIEW` etc. are visible in the listing of objects you get when you run `\d+` with no arguments. They don't seem to be in `\d+` for the object itself.
- `COMMENT ON CONSTRAINT` is visible in `\dd` for the constraint name, although there's ~no other reason to look at `\dd`, so I don't think this is worth much.
- As mentioned in the question, `COMMENT ON POLICY` doesn't appear to be visible anywhere (or maybe it's in `\dd`, but if so I don't know how to find it).

There's obviously many more of these, but these are the notes I've made so far. Feel free to edit in more.